# не работает функция заполнения для массива структур

Tags: c++, ввод

учусь программировать, хотел создал динамический массив структур в котором содержится список сотрудников магазина. Создал отдельную функцию для заполнения этого массива, но она не работает должным образом. Вместо того чтоб записывать данные по очереди, записывает во все переменные только табельный номер.

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;



int GLOBAL_NUM = 1;



struct userList
{
    int ID = 0, salary = 0;
    string name, job;
};

userList* staff = new userList[GLOBAL_NUM+1];


void staffInput()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GLOBAL_NUM; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите табельный номер:\n";
        cin >> staff[i].ID;
        cout << "\nВведите Ф.И.О. :\n";
        cin >> staff[i].name;
        cout << "\nВведите должность:\n";
        cin >> staff[i].job;
        cout << "\nВведите зарплату\n";
        cin >> staff[i].salary;
    };
};



void staffShow()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GLOBAL_NUM; i++)
    {
        cout << "------------------------" << endl;
        cout << i << '.' << endl;
        cout << "Табельный номер: " << staff[i].ID<< endl;
        cout << "Ф.И.О. : " << staff[i].ID << endl;
        cout << "Должность: " << staff[i].ID << endl;
        cout << "Зарплата: " << staff[i].ID << endl;
        cout << "------------------------" << endl;
    }
}



int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    
    cout << "введите количество заполняемых сотрудников: ";
    cin >> GLOBAL_NUM;

    staffInput();
    staffShow();
    
    return 0;
}
```

[image: результат программы:]

Comment: @NowhereMan Зависит от компилятора. `long` далеко не везде 8 байт...

Comment: @Harry вообще, принято в [битах считать](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), т.к байт не обязательно 8-битный.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ OK, не везде 64-битный :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размер `int` обычно 4 байта, так что нечто больше 3 миллиардов в него не помещается, приводит `cin` в состояние ошибки и больше вооще из него ничего не читается.

Вы же не проверяете, успешно ли считаны данные... А это ст*о*ит делать.

И еще, `>>` в строку читает одно (прописью: *ОДНО*) слово, а не строку. Это предупреждая ваш следующий вопрос...

Comment: А cin что, не повзоляет переполнение int'а? scanf'у вроде пофиг. А вот память он неправильно выделяет... А ещё, если string не прочитался, то вряд ли там это число лежит.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, с памятью весело... На память даже не глянул, у него первый же ввод слетает. `scanf`'у тоже не пофиг, но он по-другому сообщает о неприятностях не вгоняя поток в ступор :)

Comment: `scanf` спокойно допускает переполнение и возвращает свою единицу ничего не ломая: https://ideone.com/ZV2ir6.
А вот cin - действительно что-то химичит: https://ideone.com/lIZm0K - не знал об этом - думал, он себя как scanf ведёт.

Answer (score 1):

Функция заполнения-то работает (наверное), но вот функция staffShow() выводит только ID.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/907681)

Comment: @Amgarak Как раз это и есть ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @Amgarak, очень даже ответ. Точнее, вторая его треть. Ещё про выделение памяти написать осталось...